# Linux Serial RS-232, 8th bit always clear (set to 0)

Tags: linux, serial-port, termios

Below are Serial Communication Port Settings 
1. BaudRate: 19200
2. Parity: Even
3. StopBits: 1

The transmitter sends few bytes of data: 0x5A 0xA5 0xAA
Receiver is written in C on Linux using termios serial API
I am able to receive the first byte 0x5A correctly but the byte 0xA5 is received as 0x25 and 0xAA is received as 0x2A i.e. the 8th bit of each byte is set to 0...why ?
Below is the C (OS: Linux) code extract for setting the serial port settings on receiver application:

```
void *threadRecv(void *arg)
{
    char *portName = (char *)arg;
    char ch;
    struct termios portSettings;

    //fd = open(portName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    fd = open(portName, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    close(fd);
    fd = open(portName, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Error opening port: %s", portName);
        pthread_exit("Exiting thread");
    }

    cfsetispeed(&portSettings, B19200);

    //Parity
    portSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    portSettings.c_cflag |= PARENB;
    portSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;

    //Stop Bit
    portSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

    //Data Size: 8bits
    portSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    portSettings.c_cflag |= CS8;

    portSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    portSettings.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;

    portSettings.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    portSettings.c_iflag |= (INPCK);

    portSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; //For RAW I/P

    portSettings.c_cc[VMIN] = 77;
    portSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &portSettings) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error setting port: %s", portName);
        pthread_exit("Exiting thread");
    }
    while(1)
    {
        //Recv Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: `0x5A` is received as `0x2A`? If so, then this is not a bit clearing problem. The high (8th) bit of `0x5A` is already `0`.

Comment: Isn't the 8th bit the parity bit? What if you set the parity to none?

Comment: Luker sorry...the input is 0x5A 0xA5 0xAA...i have corrected

Comment: To clarify what @ArnaudKleinveld is saying, you currently have the line `portSettings.c_cflag |= PARENB;`, which is setting the parity-enabled flag. Is this deliberate (especially since it comes straight after a line that clears that bit)? What happens if you remove that line?

Comment: yes that was deliberate...I want 8E1...I have removed the line portSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;...still A5 is received as 25 and AA as 2A

Comment: Ok...if I remove Parity Check on receiver and set    portSettings.c_iflag = 0; everything works fine.

Comment: @Anjanu: Typically the hardware only supports up to 8-bit packets, so 8N1 or 7E1, but not 8E1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code follows the preferred practice of bit-wise modifying the terms of the *termios* structure, your program is missing the salient initialization of the structure by calling `tcgetattr(fd, &portSettings)`.
If the garbage values in the uninitialized *termios* stucture has the `iflag.ISTRIP` enabled, then that could explain the results you see.
Since your code only does minimal modification of the `iflag` bits, it should have a statement similar to what the `cfmakeraw()` does:

```
portSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP 
                             | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
```

See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).

---

```
portSettings.c_cc[VMIN] = 77;
portSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

This is a problematic configuration if message frame synchronization is ever lost.  Specifying a nonzero VTIME would be a safety measure that would permit recovery  as long as you have proper hunt logic for re-achieving message synchronization.

---

BTW raw (aka non-canonical) I/O is typically 8 bits with no parity.  Eight bits with parity is an unusual configuration.  Are you trying to emulate receiving 9-bit character frames (i.e. 9N1)?